# InsentService Not Called but in Manifest

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have created simple IntentService skeleton that fails to start the service. I have added the call, the main code block and the manifest entry, but I still get no log output. I have checked other similar answers here but all point to the manifest which I have added the entry to:

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name=".ApplicationGlobal">

    <service android:name=".MyIntentServiceImpl" />
```

Start Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, MyIntentServiceImpl.class);
startService(intent);
```

Service Code:

```
public class MyIntentServiceImpl extends IntentService implements MyIntentService {

private boolean result;
private Long pollingCount; 

public MyIntentServiceImpl (){
    super("MyIntentServiceImpl ");
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating Polling Service");
    this.result = false;
    this.pollingCount = 0L;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Polling Service Started");

    while(!result && (pollingCount <= MAX_POLLING_VALUE)){
        pollingCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "Polling for Result Request (" + pollingCount.toString() + ")");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Polling Service Finished");
```

Comment: Examine LogCat and look for messages around the time of your `startService()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Check LogCat. Is Android telling you that it can't find the service? That would mean that your
Intent isn't coded correctly.

Are you sure you're calling startService? You've only provided two lines from whatever calls it, and you don't show it at all in the manifest.

The way I would start debugging this is to convince myself that startService is being called.
By far the best way is to debug it using the debugger in Eclipse, *but* you could also comment out "startService" and replace it with a log statement. If that fails to show up in your log, then you know that the point where startService was is not being reached.